# How can the GKE Cluster's "The Cluster has some problem" status be fixed?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-compute-engine

I just recently began utilizing GKE. For a week, I diligently worked on spinning up a cluster.  The prior cluster and its components seem to have appeared now, however there appears to be a cluster-level error stating that "The cluster has some problem" at the cluster level. "Couldn't get data from Cluster" is what I saw when I checked the nodes tab in Cluster. There is no problem with the compute engine, however these errors are displayed at the cluster.

I tried restarting the cluster a few times because I felt it was taking a while for the node to attach to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Follow below troubleshooting steps to resolve your issue:**

- First, I advise you to [see](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/modify-project) if your project and your billing account are connected
- Next, use the commands `kubectl cluster-info` shows the cluster information.
- `kubectl get pod` -n kube-system, is the kubectl command is used to show the detailed status of the Kubernetes pods
- `kubectl get nodes` that give fundamental data about the hubs in your Kubernetes bunch. At the point when you execute this command , it speaks with the Kubernetes Programming interface server, recovering the vital data from the group's control plane.
- Try  `kubectl describe node <node>` to see the current state of your cluster.
- Additionally, look for any issues in the logs under Stackdriver -> Logging -> Logs viewer.
- Try contacting [Billing Support](https://cloud.google.com/support/) if you were unable to find any issues.

Refer to this official  [doc](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/managing-clusters) for Managing clusters

Comment: Please remove the part recommending turning off billing. That can result in resources being deleted. The OP's problem is not related to billing.